# How to select ONLY THE INDEX COLUMNS in a pandas multi-index Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Okay, so I have a DataFrame with a 2 column index, and I am trying to filter the rows from that DataFrame and keep ONLY THE INDEX COLUMNS of the original dataframe into the new filtered DataFrame.

I created the dataframe from a CSV file by: Find the CSV file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S5aaJ4uX6XUBzSz3lYZdS5owuBq3FbZa)

```
census_df = pd.read_csv("census.csv", index_col = ["STNAME", "CTYNAME"])
census_df.sort_index(ascending = True)
```

Then, I applied some filtering to the DataFrame, which works perfectly fine, and I get the desired rows. The code I used is shown below:

```
def my_answer():

    mask1 = census_df["REGION"].between(1, 2)
    mask2 = census_df.index.get_level_values("CTYNAME").str.startswith("Washington")
    mask3 = (census_df["POPESTIMATE2015"] > census_df["POPESTIMATE2014"])
    new_df = census_df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3]
    return pd.DataFrame(new_df.iloc[:, -1])

my_answer()
```

Here is the problem:

The above code returns a dataframe with the index AND the first column IN ADDITION to the 2 index columns. What I want is JUST THE TWO INDEX COLUMNS. 
So, the final answer should return a DATAFRAME, with "STNAME" and "CTYNAME", with 5 rows in it.

Comment: do you want instead `return pd.DataFrame(new_df.iloc[:, 0])` use `return new_df.reset_index()` ?

Comment: @jezrael Nope, does not work. It returns all the columns, which I do not want. I just want the columns "STNAME" and "CTYNAME". Also, I do not just want them as columns. I want them as INDICES, that too in a sorted way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `index` to `DataFrame`:

```
def my_answer():

    mask1 = census_df["REGION"].between(1, 2)
    mask2 = census_df.index.get_level_values("CTYNAME").str.startswith("Washington")
    mask3 = (census_df["POPESTIMATE2015"] > census_df["POPESTIMATE2014"])
    new_df = census_df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3]
    return pd.DataFrame(new_df.index.tolist(), columns=['STNAME','CTYNAME'])

print (my_answer())

         STNAME            CTYNAME
0          Iowa  Washington County
1     Minnesota  Washington County
2  Pennsylvania  Washington County
3  Rhode Island  Washington County
4     Wisconsin  Washington County
```

If want output as `MultiIndex` need [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html), but it working in `pandas 0.20.0+`:

```
def my_answer():

    mask1 = census_df["REGION"].between(1, 2)
    mask2 = census_df.index.get_level_values("CTYNAME").str.startswith("Washington")
    mask3 = (census_df["POPESTIMATE2015"] > census_df["POPESTIMATE2014"])
    new_df = census_df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3]
    return new_df.index.remove_unused_levels()

print (my_answer())

MultiIndex(levels=[['Iowa', 'Minnesota', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'Wisconsin'], 
                   ['Washington County']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: What you are suggesting is resetting the index, which I don't think will work for me. Although the view of the frame would be as I want, the output would not be desirable. I want the two entities - "STNAME" and "CTYNAME" - as indices, and not as columns.

Comment: @ArchanJoshi - in pandas it is possible by `return pd.DataFrame(new_df.index.tolist(), columns=['STNAME','CTYNAME']).to_string(index=False)`, but it convert dataframe to string.

Comment: but by default index cannot be removed if want `DataFrame object`

Comment: Is there no way to return a view or to somehow refer to the index columns of a dataframe, while RETAINING them as INDICES?

Comment: But if want see index columns separately, it is impossible.

Comment: After much anxiety, your solution helped me in reaching my goal. Thanks. The first solution in your answer is what worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
def my_answer():
     mask1 = census_df["REGION"].between(1, 2)
     mask2 = census_df.index.get_level_values("CTYNAME").str.startswith("Washington")
     mask3 = (census_df["POPESTIMATE2015"] > census_df["POPESTIMATE2014"])
     new_df = census_df[mask1 & mask2 & mask3]

     return pd.DataFrame([new_df.index[x] for x in range(len(new_df))])    

my_answer()
```

Output:

```
    0              1
 0  Iowa         Washington County
 1  Minnesota    Washington County
 2  Pennsylvania Washington County
 3  Rhode Island Washington County
 4  Wisconsin    Washington County``
```